# Permission Denied on SSH on Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

I'm new to Bazaar. I'm trying to setup my SSH Keys, but I'm always getting "**Permission Denied**".

Here are the things I did:

1. Open PuTTYgen
2. Click "Generate"
3. Move around the mouse pointer
4. Add a passphrase "password"
5. Click the "Save public key", and save the public key
6. Click the "Save private key", and save the private key "Private Key.ppk"
7. Login and go to https://launchpad.net/~paulmarkcastillo/+editsshkeys
8. Copy the Public Key from PuTTY Key Generator window, and paste it to the Launchpad
9. Click "Import Public Key"
10. I received an email about the new import (New SSH key added to your account).
11. Open Pageant
12. Click "Add Key"
13. Browse thru my "Private Key.ppk"
14. Enter my passphrase "password"
15. Open command line
16. Type "bzr launchpad-login paulmarkcastillo"
17. Type "bzr info lp:bzr"

Here is the **output :**

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.

How can I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell Bazaar to use putty, and thus access to the key cached by pageant, you need to set the `BZR_SSH` environment variable to point to `plink.exe`, for example:

```
set BZR_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

Also, it's probably not a problem, but I urge you to create a new key with 2048 bits encryption. When you open `puttygen.exe`, change the **Number of bits in a generated key** box from 1024 to 2048. 1024-bit keys are known to be insecure and automatically denied in modern systems. You will be more future proof with 2048-bit keys.

Finally, if the above still doesn't work, I recommend the following sanity check:

```
bzr config --remove launchpad_username --scope=bazaar
bzr info lp:bzr
```

This should work, regardless of your key setup. Later you can add back your launchpad username configuration by running `bzr lp-login paulmarkcastillo` again.

**UPDATE**

If you are using `bzr` from `Git Bash` or `cygwin` then be careful how you set `BZR_SSH`. If you set it using the environment variables screen, that should be fine. If you set it somewhere else, for example in `~/.profile`, then you need to write it differently, for example in Git Bash:

```
BZR_SSH='/c/Program Files/PuTTY/plink.exe'
# or probably this works too
BZR_SSH='C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe'
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the culprit!

It's the "ssh.exe" of both Cygwin and the Git.

What I did was removed them from the environment variable PATH

Comment: Glad you figured it out. But I think you don't need to remove the other `ssh.exe` from the `PATH` if you set `BZR_SSH`. I added a note on that to my post, see the update.