# Permission Denied on bzr info lp:bzr

Tags: bazaar

I have added my SSH Public and Private keys. But I'm still getting Permission Denied on "bzr info lp:bzr"

What am I missing? I've attached a screenshot of my Launchpad, Pageant, and the Console.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when:

- You told Bazaar your Launchpad username with `bzr lp-login USERNAME`
- ... but, Bazaar could not verify it (your access to USERNAME on Launchpad)

You can see your Launchpad username configuration with the command:

```
$ bzr config
bazaar:
  [DEFAULT]
  launchpad_username = the-username-you-set-with-bzr-lp-login
```

You can either fix your ssh key setup ([see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167877/permission-denied-on-ssh-on-bazaar/22172672#22172672)), or you can remove the `launchpad_username` setting with:

```
bzr config --remove launchpad_username --scope=bazaar
```

After this `bzr info lp:bzr` should work, unless you have other issues (for example with proxy server, network, firewalls, or others).

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the culprit!

It's the "ssh.exe" of both Cygwin and the Git.

What I did was removed them from the environment variable PATH

Comment: To "fix your ssh key" login to [launchpad.net](https://login.launchpad.net/ssh-keys) and add you ssh public key (copy&paste the text from `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`). To create a new id_rsa* keypair you can use `ssh-keygen` and just hit enter at all prompts.